# Video does not play in iOS mobile safari using Angular

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a media application using angular 7. I have used mat-video component to play video but it does not play video in iOS mobile safari. However, it successfully plays video in iOS chrome browser as well as in Mac safari. Also, i have used PWA service worker component in this application.
Please suggest, what should i do to play video in iOS mobile safari?

I have used mat-video for playing video. code is as follows:

```
<mat-video [autoplay]="true" [preload]="true" [fullscreen]="true" [download]="false" [quality]="false" spinner="spin" poster="{{subcategories.media[video_id].thumbnail_url}}" src="{{subcategories.media[video_id].videoUrl[0]}}">
```

Comment: I can't give you a decent solution, but I can tell you that iOS mobile Safari is awful when using common html5 elements, such as video or notifications. You might need to search for library to help you.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878346/aframe-video-only-plays-muted-on-ios